How to enable sound in Xiaomi Redmi Book 14 Pro in Ubuntu?
I did a fresh install of the above Ubuntu 24.04 on my new Xiaomi Redmi Book 14 Pro notebook, but there's no sound. In Sound config / Devices I only see "Dummy Output" as device.
I did everything described in various manuals, like
sudo alsa force-reload
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
apt-install --reinstall pulseaudio

along with apt remove --purge alsa-base followed by apt install alsa-base
My processor is Intel® Core™ Ultra 7 Processor 155H (result of cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name")
My soundcard is Intel (graphics: Iris Xe Graphics)

While this question was originally for Mint 22, it is also valid for Ubuntu 24.04, and is useful for this site, so I edited it accordingly.

Please edit the question and add the output of cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "model name"

You mention re-installing pulseaudio??   Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Desktop doesn't use pulseaudio, so your details of what you attempted doesn't match your released product  (Your provided command should have done nothing but generate an error anyway)

@ArchismanPanigrahi about 20 times "Intel(R) Core(TM) Ultra 87 155H"

From the Gentoo wiki

Sound support for Meteor Lake was only added in kernel 6.11, which is to the date of redaction (2024-03-09) a release candidate.

Most likely, the next version of Ubuntu (24.10, to be released in October 2024) will have this kernel. By the next point release, Ubuntu 24.04.02 (and Mint 22.1) should also have the same (or a later) kernel, and then it should work.

wow, and I didn't even write about "Meteor Lake", great you uncovered that. So effectively this means I have no chance getting sound on my notebook, but have to wait until an upcoming Linux Mint release?

Hmm. Mint 22.1 (to be released in December) and Ubuntu 24.10 (to be released in October) should have it. However, Mint has a kernel upgrader tool. The new kernel will be released in October, and you can just install the new kernel before Mint releases a new version https://fostips.com/update-kernel-linux-mint/

oh, I wasn't aware of that - Linux newbie here. Thank you for the detailed help, now I know where I'm standing and what I can do - thanks!

I have meanwhile installed the 6.11 kernel into my Linux Mint 22 installation, but sound still doesn't work, sound device is still only "Dummy Output", and apt-get update & upgrade didn't change anything either. Any idea what might still be wrong?
